# schtasks コマンドを使用したタスクスケジューラの登録で「ユーザーがログオンしているときのみ実行する」を指定したい

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

タイトルの通り、タスクスケジューラ登録を `schtasks` コマンドを用いたバッチファイルで行おうとしているのですが、「ユーザーがログオンしているときのみ実行する」の設定ができません。

`/IT` を入れると `/RU` で指定したユーザーがログインしたときのみ実行するような設定になるという記載を観たのですが、`/IT` を入れるとタスクがエラーで実行できません。

作成予定のものはsample.exeをAuto引数を付け、1日1回指定時刻(5:00)に実行するようなタスクです。

宜しくお願いします。

```
schtasks /Create ^
/tn "テストタスク" ^
/tr "'C:\AAAA\BBBB\sample.exe' Auto" ^
/sc daily /st 05:00 ^
/ru username ^
/rp pass ^
/IT
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そのエラーメッセージの詳細は何でしょう？

Comment: kunif さん、コメントいただきありがとうございます。メッセージは「タスクtestでエラーが発生しました。エラーメッセージ:選択されたタスク"{0}"が存在しません。現在のタスクを表示するには[最新の情報に更新]をクリックしてください」と出ます。特に更新しても変わりませんでした。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Windows10、タスクスケジューラで選択されたタスクが存在しませんの原因](https://excelshogikan.com/tips/tips154.html)

Comment: スクリーンショットを貼られている「タスクの作成」ダイアログでは意図する結果の設定を行うことはできるのでしょうか？ `schtasks` コマンドの問題なのかタスクスケジューラの仕様に起因する問題なのかがよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: 返答が遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。
 kunif 様＞参考リンクありがとうございます。残念ながら解決には至りませんでした。
sayuri様＞スクリーンショットで登録しているタスクはスクリプトを使用せずにタスク設定のUIから設定を行った場合は正常に動作します。スクリプトでも/ITを除き、bat実行後にタスク設定のUI「ユーザがログインしているときのみ実行」を指定すれば正常に動作します。